# A lot of iterations before converging - GLMM vs GEE question

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, sas, convergence

I'm wondering if there is any implication if a model takes 100+ iterations to converge. Can I still trust the results? I'm running cumulative logit with random intercept in proc glimmix in SAS.

EDITED TO ADD: I think I asked the question to soon and now my question is a bit different. I am thinking probably I should not trust these results. I am running 12 models and most converged with 60-100+ iterations. A few of them also had the message:
NOTE: At least one element of the (projected) gradient is greater than 1e-3. So I know there is a problem there.

So, my other alternative was to use GEE. The models estimate without a problem and actually the estimates are very close the results from the GLMM. So, now I'm confused about what I should do.

More background on the study: We have evaluations (how convincing the message is for example) of 7 messages for each subject. We also collected information on emotions and some other variables after viewing the messages. We want to examine how the emotions, etc. relate to the ratings of how convincing the messages are.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're saying that it does converge, but it takes an unusually large number of iterations, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.